# How to post the rotatable images of Plot3D to Facebook

Tags: export

I made the rotatable images of Plot3D and can post them as still images to Facebook.
Is it possible to post the rotatable images of Plot3D as rotatable to Facebook?

Comment: This is partially about FB itself, is there a way to publish an interactive content within FB posts? Once you know what is possible we might be able to help you with creating a solution.

Comment: @Kuba we’d need to know the format of their 360 degree videos, maybe?

Comment: You could export a gif file.

Comment: I could not rotate the image exported in “gif” format. I thought that DXF format of AutoCad could make us rotate it. But because I do not have AutoCad program in my PC, so I could not rotate it.